# How can I make sure this is the last change in FileSystemWatcher onChanged event?

Tags: .net, vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I am using `FileSystemWatcher` to read the contents of a file that is written to by another application. The events that happen are as follows:

1. First, the `onCreated` event happens.
2. Then, the `onChanged` event happens, an unknown number of times (sometimes it's 2, sometimes it's 3, and sometimes it's 4).

Is there a trick to know, in the handler for the `onChanged` event, that this is the last time this file is being written to by the other application?

Comment: In theory, clearly no. Unless you have special knowledge of the other application, how would you know what it is doing and what it will be doing?

Comment: you could start a BGW or thread which "watches" the new file; try to open it exclusively and when you no longer get an IO Exception, it is complete or at least safe to use/copy/move/open.  If it waits 1-2 secs before the first try, you might get it to succeed on the first Try, if not provide a timeout before trying again.  A max tries bailout would probably be appropriate in cases where something goes wrong and it remains locked.

Comment: Agree with Pluto - the only way you can be sure is to lock the file.  this may cause exception in the other application.

Comment: See http://weblogs.asp.net/ashben/31773 apparently multiple events being raised is a known issue

Comment: Like PMF said, there's no way to know unless you have knowledge of the other application. If you know the application takes 10 seconds to do modification, you could wait 15 seconds before accessing the file.

Comment: Did you have any control on the other application? I mean, can you change its code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any duplicated `OnChanged` events from the `FileSystemWatcher` can be detected and discarded by checking the `File.GetLastWriteTime` timestamp on the file in question. Like so:

```
Private lastRead As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

Private Sub OnChanged(source As Object, a As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Dim lastWriteTime As DateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(uri)
    If lastWriteTime <> lastRead Then
        doStuff()
        lastRead = lastWriteTime
    End If
    ' else discard the (duplicated) OnChanged event
End Sub
```

Another approach is discussed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102493/Enhanced-FileSystemWatcher)

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle these by waiting a predefined am out of time and verifying the file hasn't changed since that last check.

IE:

Change event fires

Start timer (use tasks these days)(for some small amount of time ~seconds usually)

If change event fires again, reset timer/task delay

Once the task executes that means the writes have settled down for at least a few seconds, indicating that the file access is done.

*Tweaking the timeout may be needed in some cases depending on file size and accessing programs